# Causative relative sentence

Tags: grammar, causation

> #### 合併
>
> ②〔法〕複数の会社が一つになる組織再編行為。会社の権利義務を既存の別会社に承継**させる**吸収合併と、新設する会社に承継**させる**新設合併とがある。
>
> (Law) The process through which different companies become one. The merger which let the administration privileges to another pre-existing company and
> the new company which the new coalition makes (the administration privileges) inherit.

Am I wrong?
How could I parse this?

Comment: Translation check is off topic. See http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I should have asked openly that I had trouble with the relative construction and needed an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English vs Japanese causative

> English: *I made him eat worms.*
>
> Japanese: 私が彼に虫を食べさせた。

In other words:

> *A* makes *B* do *V* *V<sub>obj</sub>* = *A* が *B* に *V<sub>obj</sub>* を *V* させる

The important part is that, in causative structure, **what を attaches to is the object of the action**, but not the causee (who is enforced). **The causee is marked by に**.

Thus, the given passage should be translated as:

> The reorganization process through which different companies become one. There are: absorption-type merger, which lets another pre-existing company inherit the company's legal rights and obligations; and consolidation-type merger, which lets a new company inherit them.

<sub>(The legal information provided is, at best, of a general nature and cannot substitute for the advice of a licensed professional blah blah...)</sub>

Comment: I was not sure bacause of the relative form of the sentences.
By reading your translation and re-reading the japanese I think I understand it better.